# Managing fragments in Android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

Hello i am fairly new to android development and have been using Activities to navigate through my app. Now that i have gotten my feet wet i'd like to write more efficient applications.  From what i have read, fragments are a way to limit the creation of unnecessary Activities and reuse UI elements.

I am trying reduce the amount of activities in my applications by converting them to fragments.  When a button is clicked, do i call the next fragment from the current fragment,  is this good or bad practice? What is the role of the main activity if fragments are directing the flow of the application?

Comment: main activity is the fragment container

Comment: A great resource for beginners https://www.udacity.com/course/android-basics-user-input--ud836

Answer (score 0):

Fragment is good practice but you need more careful handling fragment because it's tight coupling is when a group of classes are highly dependent on one another.

read this tutorial it will help to understand fragment flow [https://guides.codepath.com/android/creating-and-using-fragments]

Fragment is view and Activity is parent View (MainController is must be actvity)